# composer install Doctrine/DBAL fails in Laravel 9 with PHP 8.2

Tags: laravel, composer-php

I got an error when trying to install doctrine/dbal in order to add timestamp type according to laravel doc in order to allow changing timestamp column in migration.
Here is the message

```
composer require doctrine/dbal
Using version ^3.6 for doctrine/dbal
./composer.json has been updated
Running composer update doctrine/dbal
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - nette/schema v1.2.2 requires php >=7.1 <8.2 -> your php version (8.2.2) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - league/commonmark 2.3.5 requires league/config ^1.1.1 -> satisfiable by league/config[v1.1.1].
    - laravel/framework v9.30.0 requires league/commonmark ^2.2 -> satisfiable by league/commonmark[2.3.5].
    - league/config v1.1.1 requires nette/schema ^1.2 -> satisfiable by nette/schema[v1.2.2].
    - laravel/framework is locked to version v9.30.0 and an update of this package was not requested.
```

How can I deal with that ? Installing nette/schema before ?

Comment: "Installing nette/schema before ?" - why not try that? That package in that specific version is not compatible with PHP 8.2, as given in the error message

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's saying that a depency cannot be updated / installed with your PHP version. Pay special atention to this line:

```
 - nette/schema v1.2.2 requires php >=7.1 <8.2 -> your php version (8.2.2) does not satisfy that requirement.
```

You have to check another `nette/schema` version that support `PHP version 8.2.2` (your version) or downgrade PHP